# lines of code between time frame in sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I would like to know if Sonar has the option to provide the report for lines of code changed/inserted/updated between the given timeframe ?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Sonar can't really do this: it will tell you if the total of lines has changed, but e.g., if you were to remove 1000 lines, change 1000 lines and add 1000 lines, Sonar would see that the total number of lines is the same, so no obvious change (on that metric anyway).

You can get some information with the [SCM Activity Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin), and more with Sonar 2.5 (which seems to add better support for differential measures).  But I'm not sure if it will be completely what you are looking for; I can't tell what the full set of metrics is.  Nonetheless, that's where I would focus effort for improvements if I were you.

For a more detailed report on changes of this nature you should be able to get the information directly from your version control system.